# Customise a custom product attribute input renderer in Magento 2 the right way

Tags: magento2, blocks, adminhtml, renderer

I'm facing to a very ridiculous trouble, I added a custom product attribute with source model, backend model as a select box. Everything works fine (my custom attribute will get the values from a custom table) except the `input_renderer` part.

Here is what I tried, (running on default mode)

> Setup\MySetup.php

```
public function getDefaultEntities()
{
    return [
        'catalog_product' => [
            'entity_model' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product',
            'attribute_model' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute',
            'table' => 'catalog_product_entity',
            'additional_attribute_table' => 'catalog_eav_attribute',
            'entity_attribute_collection' => 'Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection',
            'attributes' => [
                'custom_ids' => [
                    'type' => 'static',
                    'input' => 'select',
                    'label' => 'Custom Attribute',
                    'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'backend' => 'Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\CustomAttr',
                    'source' => 'Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\CustomAttr',
                    'input_renderer' => 'Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\CustomAttr',
                    'required' => false,
                    'sort_order' => 9,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'group' => 'General',
                    'is_used_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
                    'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
                ],
    ];
}
```

> Block\Adminhtml\Product\Helper\Form\CustomAttr.php

```
class CustomAttr extends \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Select
{
    public function getAfterElementHtml()
    {
        if (!$this->isAllowed()) {
            return '';
        }

        $htmlId = $this->getHtmlId();
        $suggestPlaceholder = __('start typing to search custom attribute');
        $selectorOptions = $this->jsonEncoder->encode($this->getSelectorOptions());
        $backendUrl = $this->backendData->getUrl('vendor_module/customattr_index/index/suggestCustomAttr');

        $return
            = <<<HTML
   /** Some HTML and JavaScript here **/
HTML;

        return $return;
    }
}
```

I tried to `die()` inside `getAfterElementHtml()` method, but nothing happens. I even go to the database and change the value of column `frontend_input_renderer` in table `catalog_eav_attribute` to something doesn't exists.

But there is **NO ERROR** at all !!! Magento 2 just simply to denied to call my input renderer :)

Anyone here have any suggestions or a best pratices for this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## TL;DR: If you need to customise your custom attribute in product edit form Magento 2, use [PHP modifier in UI components](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_modifier_concept.html) instead of input renderer.

I found the solution myself.

As we all knew that Magento 2 using UI components, the solution I'm talking about here is [PHP modifier in UI components](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_modifier_concept.html).

From Magento 2 devdocs:

> PHP modifiers that are the server-side part of [UI components
>   configuration](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts//ui_comp_config_flow_concept.html). Using modifiers is optional and might be necessary when
>   [static declaration in XML configuration files](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_xmldeclaration_concept.html) is not suitable for the
>   tasks. For example, in cases when additional data should be loaded
>   from database. Or the other specific example is the [default product
>   creation form](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/customize_product.html), for which the modifier is a place where validations are
>   added to display only certain fields for certain product types.

By default, Magento 2 using PHP modifiers to render EAV attribute. They never use `input_renderer` to do so. If you are reading here, I assume that you need few examples, so here you are :)

> Ui\DataProviders\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomAttr

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;

/**
 * Data provider for "Custom Attribute" field of product page
 */
class CustomAttr extends AbstractModifier
{
    const SUGGEST_FILTER_URI = 'vendor_module/something/suggestCustomAttr';

    /**
     * @param LocatorInterface            $locator
     * @param UrlInterface                $urlBuilder
     * @param ArrayManager                $arrayManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        ArrayManager $arrayManager
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $meta = $this->customiseCustomAttrField($meta);

        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Customise Custom Attribute field
     *
     * @param array $meta
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function customiseCustomAttrField(array $meta)
    {
        $fieldCode = 'custom_ids'; //your custom attribute code
        $elementPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath($fieldCode, $meta, null, 'children');
        $containerPath = $this->arrayManager->findPath(static::CONTAINER_PREFIX . $fieldCode, $meta, null, 'children');

        if (!$elementPath) {
            return $meta;
        }

        $meta = $this->arrayManager->merge(
            $containerPath,
            $meta,
            [
                'arguments' => [
                    'data' => [
                        'config' => [
                            'label'         => __('Custom Attribute'),
                            'dataScope'     => '',
                            'breakLine'     => false,
                            'formElement'   => 'container',
                            'componentType' => 'container',
                            'component'     => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group',
                            'scopeLabel'    => __('[GLOBAL]'),
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                'children'  => [
                    $fieldCode => [
                        'arguments' => [
                            'data' => [
                                'config' => [
                                    'component'     => 'Vendor_Module/js/components/your-select-js',
                                    'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                                    'formElement'   => 'select',
                                    'elementTmpl'   => 'ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select',
                                    'disableLabel'  => true,
                                    'multiple'      => false,
                                    'options'       => $this->getOptions(),
                                    'filterUrl'     => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                                        self::SUGGEST_FILTER_URI,
                                        ['isAjax' => 'true']
                                    ),
                                    'config'           => [
                                        'dataScope' => $fieldCode,
                                        'sortOrder' => self::FIELD_ORDER,
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );

        return $meta;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve custom attribute collection
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        // Get your options
    }
}
```

> etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom-attribute" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomAttr</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Above is example of two important file which ping Magento 2 to render your custom attribute fields in product edit form to whatever you want. You will need to customise with javascript if you want it plays smoothly.

#### And yes, welcome to Magento 2 most painful's world - UI components.

Comment: be sure that sortOrder is more than 150 ;)

Comment: This works for the product edit form but does not seem to work for the attribute mass update form. From what I can see the attribute form doesn't use UI components yet. I don't know why Magento allowed this kind of inconsistency!

Comment: Great tips, thanks! I am also trying to so this type of thing without any luck. Do you know how I could only replace a custom product attribute field by a block such as: $this->layoutFactory->create()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\MyBlock')->toHtml() ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have errors disabled, can you turn developer mode on by using the Magento CLI or you can add this near your code `error_reporting(-1);`

`bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html

Comment: I tried both but nothing happened.