# Magento 2.1: adding custom field in product form by ui component

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, product-attribute

I'm trying to add a new custom field in product form using Ui Component so I've created the install script, **My/Module/Setup/InstallData.php**:

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory /* For Attribute create  */;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $_eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
         */
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'file_uploader_attribute', /* File Uploader Attribute */
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'backend' => '',
                'label' => 'File Uploader Attribute (Filename)',
                'input' => 'file',
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => false,
                'required' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => true
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

and the product Ui Component, **My/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml**:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="file_uploader_attribute_fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">More Product Links</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="product[file_uploader_attribute]">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">file</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">product[file_uploader_attribute]</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

It has created new eav attribute into db and it has added element into HTML product form, all correctly.

The only issue is that the HTML element has not *name* attribute (see image) so the post request doesn't send the field value.

[image]

If I force in the code to set *name* attribute all works fine.

How can I set *name* attribute by Ui Component?

Comment: It might be duplicated to https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139480/customise-a-custom-product-attribute-input-renderer-in-magento-2-the-right-way/

Answer (score 4):

Field name should be `file_uploader_attribute`, not `product[file_uploader_attribute]`.

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="file_uploader_attribute_fieldset">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">More Product Links</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="opened" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">2</item>
                <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="file_uploader_attribute">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">file</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">product[file_uploader_attribute]</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

See: [Magento2 DevDoc: Customize product creation form](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/customize_product.html)

Comment: I've already tried without success..
The product form has input file element without "name" attribute.

Comment: I'm sorry I did not notice that it has blank name attribute. The best solution for now is to modify your product form using modifier pool.